# Can't use array functions like .includes in Object literals

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object-literal

I'm trying to organise my react state in object literals consisting of arrays.

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState({ filter: [], other: [] });
```

I want to update my filter array, whenever a click on a list item occurs.

```
    const handleListItemClick = (event, index) => {
    if (state['filter'].includes(index)) {
        setState(state['filter'].filter(function (element) {
            return element != index;
        }))
    } else {
        setState(state['filter'].concat([index]));
    }
};
```

But whenever I try to access the filter array, java script can't resolve array functions like includes or indexOf, for instance:

```
<ListItem
          button
          selected={state['filter'].includes(0)}
          onClick={(event) => handleListItemClick(event, 0)}>
                <ListItemText primary="Kundensegmente" />
</ListItem
```

I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: state.filter.includes is not a function

Using functions like includes seems to work in one-dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original shape of the state was this:

> ```
> { filter: [], other: [] }
> ```

But then you changed it:

> ```
> setState(state['filter'].concat([index]));
> ```

You replaced the **whole** state with the value of `fiter` (an empty array) concatinated with a new array `[index]`.

That new array doesn't have a `filter` property.

---

Use separate states for `filter` and `other`.

```
const [filter, setFilter] = React.useState([]);
const [other, setOther] = React.useState([]);
```

---

Alternatively, if you really want to keep them merged into a single object, then you need to maintain the shape of that object in the state.

Create a new object which is the same as the old object except for **just** the bits you want to change.

```
setState({
    ...state,
    filter: state.filter.concat([index]);
});
```

Comment: As alternative, he can return the old state along with new one like `setState((prev) => {
    return { ...prev, filter: prev.filter.concat([index]) }
})`

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought you could only use one state per component